# Target dynamically added element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dynamically-generated, event-delegation

I know how to use evenet Delegation on jQuery. To listen an even on dynamically added element I have to use following..

```
$('body .some-class').on('click', '.dynamically_added_ele', function(){});
```

I understand it quite. Come to actual problems. Suppose I have a button and DOM element which I want to add on document dynamically.

```
<button class="my-button">Click Me</button>
var newDom = '<p class="new-dom">Hello there I am new content</p>';
```

Now I am binding click event on button to create new element

```
var allow = true;
$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
    var newDom = '<p class="new-dom">Hello there I am new content</p>';
    if( allow ) {
       $(this).after($(newDom));
    } else {
        $(newDom).remove(); // Not removing the new added element. Can't target that newly added element
    }
    allow = false;
});
```

**variable** `allow` will check to be `true` then jQuery will create that element and last `allow` variable will be `false`. When again use click that button allow will be `false` and that time jQuery should remove the newly added element. But here I am facing the problems. I am not able to remove that newly added element like what I have coded above.

What can I do now?

Comment: You are trying to remove it before putting into it to DOM, that is your mistake. Why you are not using a class selector to remove all "new-dom" class elements

$(".new-dom").remove();

Comment: @tanaydin I got it and got the problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
var allow = true;
var newDom = $('<p class="new-dom">Hello there I am new content</p>');

$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
    if( allow ) {
       $(this).after(newDom);
       allow = false;
    } else {
        newDom.remove();
        allow = true;
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="my-button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to use class selector like this

```
var allow = true;
$('.my-button').on('click', function(){
    var newDom = '<p class="new-dom">Hello there I am new content</p>';
    if( allow ) {
        $(this).after($(newDom));
        allow = false;
    } else {
       $('.new-dom').remove();
       allow = true;
    }
 });
```